# Is this SQL line saying previous day or the next day?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a old sql script that looks to get data from the previous day. So in our table we have a DatePlaced column, we want to be able to get all the records from the time it was ran til the previous day. Thanks for any help.

```
where  DATEDIFF(DAY,[DatePlaced],GETDATE()) = 1
```

Comment: it returns true if `DatePlaced` is yesterday

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ugh, don't do it this way. Applying a function to the column means any index is relatively useless. To get data for yesterday (or any range, for that matter), try:

```
DECLARE @today DATE = SYSDATETIME();

...
  WHERE DatePlaced >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, @today)
    AND DatePlaced <  @today;
```

If you are on an old version like SQL Server 2005, then instead:

```
DECLARE @today DATETIME;
SET @today = DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE());

...
  WHERE DatePlaced >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, @today)
    AND DatePlaced <  @today;
```

Comment: Note that in the first example, it will include all time up to the current time today as part of the query, and only the portion yesterday that is after that time (yesterday). You may want to truncate away the time portion in that first piece of code. Ie. first piece of code will include 16.07.2013 14:40 - 17.07.2013 14:40, whereas the second piece of code will include the entire 16.07.2013 and nothing from 17.07.2013.

Comment: @Lasse no it won't; did you look at the code or try it? It's essentially `CONVERT(DATE` which eliminates time.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `DATE` type of the @today variable, and yes, I did try "it", but of course I tried it with `DATETIME` since I essentially took your second example and rewrote it.

Comment: @Lasse Ctrl + C is your friend.

Answer (score 6):

It means yesterday.

Today is `2013-07-17`. I have run the following queries to verify:

```
select datediff(day,'2013-07-16',getdate()) --returns 1
select datediff(day,'2013-07-18',getdate()) --returns -1
```

For more information, see [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx):

> ```
> DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
> ```